# Proving a Trig. Identity

Tags: trigonometry

How would one prove the following identity algebraically?
$$\cos^{-1}(\sin(\cos\theta)=-\cos\theta+\frac\pi2$$
Graphing the LHS on a graphing utility clearly reveals that it is a transformation of a sine or cosine function; however, it is unclear as to how one would approach this algebraically.

Answer (score 2):

You can derivate $$f\colon\theta\mapsto \cos^{-1}(\sin(\cos(\theta)))+\cos(\theta)$$

then you get

$$f'(\theta)=\frac{\sin(\cos^2(\theta))}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\cos(\theta))}}-\sin(\theta)=0$$

because of the relation $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$.

Then you know that $f$ is constante, and you can look at $f(\pi/2)$ for instance and you get

$$\forall \theta, \quad f(\theta)=\frac\pi 2$$

so

$$\forall \theta, \quad\cos^{-1}(\sin(\cos(\theta)))=-\cos(\theta)+\frac \pi 2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $\varphi=\cos\theta$, $\psi=\arccos(\sin \varphi)$. This is equivalent to
$$\cos\psi=\sin\varphi=\cos\Bigl(\varphi-\frac\pi2\Bigr)\quad\textbf{and}\quad 0\le\psi\le \pi.$$
The general solution of the trigonometric equation is
$$\psi\equiv\pm\Bigl(\varphi-\frac\pi2\Bigr)\mod 2\pi.$$
Now, $\;\varphi\in[-1,1]\subset\big[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\big]$, hence $\;\varphi-\frac\pi2\in[-\pi,0]$. This  to satisfy $\psi\in[0,\pi]$, we have to take the solution
$$\psi=-\Bigl(\varphi-\frac\pi2\Big)=\frac\pi2-\varphi=\frac\pi2-\cos\theta.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

take  $ \cos \theta = \alpha$  and remember that:
$$
\cos^{-1} X= Y \quad \iff \quad \cos Y =X
$$

so, your identity says that:
$$
\cos (\pi/2 - \alpha)=\sin \alpha
$$

(well known).  Do you see that?

Comment: It is *not* equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that, for every $t\in[-1,1]$,
$$
\arccos t+\arcsin t=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
and so
$$
\arccos\sin\cos\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin\sin\cos\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\cos\theta
$$